# Working with Jobs in BigQuery Connector in WSO2 EI 6.5.0 - maxResults limit in runQuery Operation

Tags: google-bigquery, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am using [BigQuery connector](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/connectors/bigquery-connector/bigquery-connector-reference/) in `WSO2 EI 6.5.0`

There is an operation called [runQuery](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-bigquery/blob/master/docs/jobs.md) to fetch data from bigquery table.

Below is the usage of `maxResult` as per [this Google doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query),

```
maxResult - The maximum number of rows of data (results) to return per page. Responses are also limited to 10 MB. By default, there is no maximum row count and only the byte limit applies.
```

- Is there any default limit will be applied if i'm not passed this param? if yes how many rows will return after execute `runQuery`?
- if not, what is the max limit I can pass to this `maxResult` param?

For POC purpose, given `maxresults` as `10000`. When it comes to PRODUCTION we may get more than  `100000` of records(As per estimation `300000 - 400000 records`)

Not sure in runtime what happened, this row count may increase.

So what is the solution for this situation? Kindly clarify on the same.

Comment: Please use standard measurements. Not everyone understands what a *lakh* is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [code](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-bigquery/blob/master/src/main/resources/bigquery-jobs/runQuery.xml#L86) WSO2 will not send this parameter if you don't set it. So WSO2 is not setting any defaults here, hence whatever limit is enforced by Bigquery will apply to the request. As per the Bigquery documentation, it states `By default, there is no maximum row count, and only the byte limit applies.` So the answer is there is no default limit.

As per the maximum limit, this varies on the dataset I believe, as per the documentation it's best to have a smaller number that will paginate the dataset and then you can page through them. This will improve reliability and probably resource exhaustion as well.

From Google doc.

> Setting this flag to a small value such as 1000 and then paging
> through results might improve reliability when the query result set is
> large.

Comment: Hi @ycr,
Thanks for your clarification. From above answer i got to know that we should manually pass this maxresult param as WSO2 connector not setting any default value. In regards to max limit, I am doing ETL job which run an every hour, for the schedule time , whatever data present in source, all those data needs to be pushed to target system (for eg. 100000 records present in bigquery table in duration (03.00 PM to 04.00 PM), same number of records  pushed to target system while cron run), hence i am seeking for that max limit. if i put 1000, remaining 9000 records i may missed to push.

Comment: @Justin Yeah, if you don't handle the pagination it would miss data. The whole idea of pagination is to load data as partitions(pages) then once the page is processed we fetch the next page and so on. SO this way all the data is not loaded at once. I haven't done this in Bigquery, so if implementing you may have to do some research on it. Hope this helps.